# Вертикальные полосы между изображениями в письмах

Tags: вёрстка, табличная-верстка

```css
#backgroundTable {margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important; line-height:100% !important;}
      .outer {Margin: 0 auto; width: 600px;}
      body {margin: 0; padding: 0; min-width: 100%; width: 100% !important; height: 100% !important;}
      body, table, td, div, p, a {-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;}
      table, td {mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; border-collapse:collapse !important; border-spacing:0;}
      img {clear:both; outline:none; text-decoration:none; -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;} 
      a img {border:none; outline:none; clear:both; text-decoration:none;} 
      p,a,span,li,td,body,table{-ms-text-size-adjust:100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;}
      p{margin:0;padding:0;}
      div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {margin:0 !important;}
      .imageFix {display:block;}
      #outlook a, a {padding:0;}
      .ReadMsgBody {width:100%;}
      .ExternalClass {width:100%;}
      .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height:100%;}
      table{margin:0; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;}
      td{padding:0;}
      .preheader{font-size:1px; color:#ffffff; line-height:1px; max-height:0px; max-width:0px;}
      [if mso]>
      .fallback-text{font-family:Arial,sans-serif;}
      <![endif]
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Тема</title>   
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="backgroundTable">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table class="outer" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="preheader">Preheader</div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="bottom">
                <p style="line-height:1px;">
                  <a href="" target="_blank"><img width="600" height="" border="0" src="http://www.gold585.ru/upload/subscribe/06-07-2018/30.png" alt=""></a>
                  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img width="600" height="" border="0" src="http://www.gold585.ru/upload/subscribe/06-07-2018/31.png" alt=""></a>
                  </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Бордеры и междубордерные отступы само собой убраны. 
Уже все было испробавано, результат с пиксельным зазором в outlook. Может кто сталкивался [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отформатируйте, пожалуйста, код. Здесь же не роботы это читают. .

Comment: А зачем у p line-height:1px, а не 0?

Comment: был найден такой совет http://htmlbook.ru/faq/kak-razmestit-slitno-dva-izobrazheniya-drug-pod-drugom
но даже если поставить 0, это не поможет